# Attach event using Javascript

Tags: javascript

I'd like to attach an event when a function is called, but it seems not working using `addEventListener`...

My code :

```
function add () {
  this.inputString.input.addEventListener('mouseover', toggle.call(this));
}

function toggle () {
  $(this.tooltip).toggle();
}
```

Issue : the `toggle()` function doesn't work. However, `this.inputString.input` and `this.tooltip` are not emtpy...

Comment: what is "this" here?

Comment: If you want to bind a certain `this` use `bind` instead of `call`

Comment: Why it works with `bind` instead of `call` ?

Comment: `call` would "call" (i.e. invoke) the function immediately, `bind` would return a "bound function", which could be used as a handler.

Answer (score 1):

The apparent problem I see here is that you should **attach a function** to `addEventListener`'s second argument, not the call itself:

```
this.inputString.input.addEventListener('mouseover', toggle);
```

Then you should consider reviewing the `toggle()` function itself.
What do you mean by `this.tooltip` ?

But this is out of scope of this question (about attaching events).